# Finding side of triangle given central angle and radius of the described circle

Tags: geometry

Given $\triangle ABC$, is described around $k(O; R)$ and $\angle AOC = 120$, $\angle CAB=\alpha$ find$AB$. The answer is $2R\sin(120-\alpha)$ However I don't know how to prove it. Here is drawing:
[image]

Comment: By the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) you have $\angle COB=2 \alpha$; then you can find $\angle AOB$ and finally use the chord-length formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$COA$ and $AOB$ are isosceles triangles, so:
$$
\angle CAO=30° \quad \Rightarrow \quad \angle OAB=\alpha-30°
$$
so :
$$
AB=2R\cos(\alpha-30°)=2R \sin (90°-\alpha+30°)
$$

Comment: How did you get that $AB=2Rcos(\alpha-30)$

Comment: Because $AOB$ is isosceles with side $R$ and the angle at the basis is $\alpha-30°$, so the distance from  $A$ to the midpoint of the basis is $R\cos (\alpha-30°)$.

Comment: Mind giving name of this theorem (the distance from A to the midpoint is $side*cos\alpha$) or link to proof?

Comment: You should be able to derive the proof on your own. Cut the the isosceles triangle in half by drawing a line from O to the midpoint H of AB.  You have OA = OB=R, angle OAH = angle OBH = $\alpha - 30$ and AH = HB=1/2 AB.  So the two small triangles are congruent.  So angle AHO and angle BHO are congruent and linear so they are both right angles.  By definition AH = OA cos OAH = R cos $\alpha - 30$.  So AB = AH + AB = 2AH = 2R cos $\alpha - 30$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw perpendicular bisector of $AB$ from $O$, name the intersection $H$.

You can see $\angle OAH=\alpha-30^\circ$, so $AH=R\cos(\alpha-30^\circ)=R\sin(-(\alpha-30^\circ-\dfrac\pi2))=R\sin(120^\circ-\alpha)$

And

$AB=2AH=2R\sin(120^\circ-\alpha)$

Comment: I don't understand from where did you get $AH=Rcos(\alpha-30)$ and 
$AB=2AH$

Comment: Consider the right triangle $\triangle AOH$ with $\angle AHO=90^\circ$. Also note $\angle OAC=30^\circ$

Comment: And because $k$ is the circum-circle of $\triangle ABC$, every perpendicular line from $O$ to the sides bisects it. Hence, $AB=2AH$

Comment: Two basic facts and two conclusions: i) given a right triangle base = hyp x cos(base angle) (def.) ii) for an isosceles triangle the angle bisector of the vertex is the perpendicular bisector of the base (the angle bisector cuts the triangle into two triangles that must be congruent so by corresponding parts the base must be bisected. The distances are the same so the base is perpendicularly bisected) THEREFORE iii) an isosceles triangle is "two congruent right triangles glued together" and so iv) the base of an isosceles triangle is 2 x side x cos(base angle)

Answer (score 0):

Given a right triangle with hypotenuse $h$ and base angle $\theta$ and base leg of length $b$.  By definition $\cos \theta = b/h$ so $b = h*\cos \theta$.

Now take an isosceles triangle with congruent sides $s$ and congruent base angles $\theta$. "cut" the isosceles triangle in two by drawing the line from its top vertex to the midpoint of its base.  This cuts the triangle into two smaller triangles.

These two triangles are congruent as they both have sides $s$, angles $\theta$ and sides $1/2$ the base.  So the new angles opposite the $\theta$ angles are both congruent and linear so they are right angles and we have cut the isosceles triangle into two right triangles.

So 1/2 the base of the isosceles triangle is $s* \cos \theta$.  So the base of an a isosceles triangle is $2s*\cos \theta$.

So in your diagram OAB would be an isosceles triangle so $AB = 2*R \cos OAB$.

Now $OAC = 1/2(180-120) = 30$  $CAB = \alpha$ so $OAB = \alpha - 30$.

So $AB = 2*R \cos (\alpha - 30)$.

Now if you draw a unit circle you can see that $\cos \theta = \sin (90 - \theta)$.  (Do I need to prove it?$*$)

So $AB = 2*R \sin (90 - (\alpha - 30)) = 2*R \sin (120 - \alpha)$.

=====

$*$ Consider the points $O = (0,0), A= (\sin(90 - \theta),0), B (\sin(90 - \theta), \cos (90 - \theta)$.

Consider the right triangle $OAB$.

Then $OA = AB*\cos AOB = 1*\cos AOB = \cos (90 - (90 -\theta)) = \cos \theta$.

But $OA = |(0,0) -  (\sin(90 - \theta),0)| = \sin(90 - \theta)$.

So $\cos \theta - \sin(90-\theta)$.